# Как в Fedora 36 настроить подключение OpenVpn не используя openvpn3

Tags: gui, openvpn, fedora

У меня на компьютере установлена Fedora 36 Workstation. Я зарегистрировался на сайте OpenVPN и скачал файл .ovpn. Я искал в интернете способ подключения к VPN с помощью этого файла, но не нашел ничего кроме подключения через openvpn3. Если кто-нибудь знает какой- нибудь другой способ желательно через файл .ovpn, подскажите пожалуйста. Хотелось бы какую-нибудь GUI-шку.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный NetworkManager умеет в OpenVPN https://www.tune-it.ru/web/leksa/blog/-/blogs/2209949